# Is it possible to keep only coloured parts in an image, removing all the rest (in greyscale)?

Tags: image-processing

I would like to know if it is possible to keep only coloured parts (for example red eyes) from a b/w image, removing all the other parts not coloured (i.e. in grayscale or black and white). 
I was thinking of `RemoveBackground` or in using

```
mask=DeleteSmallComponents@
  ColorNegate@DeleteSmallComponents@MorphologicalBinarize[img, ...], 
 DiskMatrix[...]
```

but it removes also the coloured parts..
 Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time. I really appreciate your help. 
Please find below an example of picture.

[image]

(Courtesy: https://vustudents.ning.com/profiles/blogs/the-red-focus-black-and-white-photography-with-red-focus)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. More people would be willing to show you how if you would provide a sample picture for people to work with.

Comment: Sorry, C.E.. I thought I was adding it on the post, but I did not click on add at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's split this image into three channels: hue, saturation, and brightness.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwwmp.jpg"];
{h, s, b} = ColorSeparate[img, "HSB"]
```

[image: Color separation]

It turns out that the leave has a much higher saturation than the black and white background. By using `Binarize`, we can create a white mask for the region that the leave covers. And finally, we get this:

```
ImageMultiply[img, Binarize[s]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks C.E.. I did not think to separate the colour, but only to remove the background. Thank you very much. The result is awesome!